# What is meant by a framework running "on top of" node.js, as it would need to be explained to a beginner?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, mean-stack

Assuming the subject has a beginner's understanding of JavaScript, how would "on top of node.js" be explained in layman's programming terms.  I'd like to know in general as well as specifically in reference to Express on top of node.js in the MEAN stack.  Thank you.

Comment: It "runs on" that something. It's like saying "cars run on gas".

Comment: It means that it either expects to run in a Node environment or it's an app that comes bundled with Node. Express is a framework that only works in a Node environment.

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer: My car runs on the street. It doesn't fly - that might be a better example for the "environment" it "runs in".

Answer (score 1):

Think of Node as the gears that turn and make things work, and a package like

- Meteor
- Sails
- Express

The chain that makes these gears turn, but not only do they turn the gears they also grease the chain for you, take out links when the chain gets loose, so on so forth

They run on top of Node because they make it so you don't have to do any of the grunt work to make it work, you can just go in deploy a new Express project and not have to worry about setting headers on responses, cookies, creating the server, dealing with all that, for the most part you can just hop on and go

Comment: Thanks for the great analogy. I'm only a beginner so getting explanations that paint an overall picture helps visualize different ways things are connected. Sometimes it's easy to get lost in the details as a beginner and miss the bigger concepts at work. I'm currently trying to gain that perspective with respect to the MEAN stack.